# How do I setup an environment for Swift programming on OS X?

Tags: macos, swift

As the title,I just want to do some simple practice ranther than big project for I'm just new to `Swift` language.So is there any way to setup an environment for `Swift` without 'Xcode 6' installed?
THX for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment.
The [Swift Language](http://developer.apple.com/swift) is actually new and still in development, evolving day after day.

This means also that new funcitions and classes will be created and modified int the next months. Until then no one will create an "Online Playground" for Swift or similar.

I've planned to make an online Apple Swift Playgroung myself, but that will be once the language has finished developing.

You need XCode 6 to try and use the Swift language, even only in Apple Playground.

Comment: oops.<br/>I just found a site `http://swift-lang.org/` from the the site of developer center of Apple.I'm wondering what the differences are between there two `Swift`?Because I can run the sample programs from the files I downloaded but I can't run the code from Apple's tutorial.

Comment: That's completely a different language and is for parallel scripting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Swift without installing Xcode6. It isn't a stand alone language at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

With each beta of Swift, Apple is changing the language. At the moment [August 2014] noone could make a lightweight environment of Swift, because of these many changes.

If you think that you have to pay for playing around with the Xcode 6 Beta, this isn't true. You don't need the "Mac Developer Plan" for 99 US$/year.

You only need to register as a developer at this page: 
https://developer.apple.com/

If you're done, than you can download the Xcode 6 Beta at this page:
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

After installing Xcode 6, you can start a new "Playground", which is your lightweight environment for Switch you're searching.